# Calculating Conditional Expectation - Billinglsey

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Theorem 34.5 on page 449 of Billinsley's 3rd edition of Probability and Measure states (notation mine)

> Let $\Lambda_{X \mid Y}$ be a conditional distribution with respect to $\sigma(Y)$ of a random variable $X$.  If $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Borel-measurable and $\phi(X)$ is integrable, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x)\, \Lambda_{x \mid y}(dx \mid Y(\omega))$ is a version of $E(\phi(X) \mid \sigma(Y))(\omega)$.

I'd like to test my understanding of this theorem by computing $E(X \mid Y)$ where $X \mid Y \sim exp(Y)$, where the conditional pdf is $p(x \mid y) = \frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}$ for $x,y > 0$:
\begin{align*}
E(X \mid Y)(\omega) & = \int_{[0,\infty)}x \, \Lambda_{X \mid Y}(dx \mid Y(\omega)) \\
& = \int_0^\infty x \frac{1}{Y(\omega)}e^{-x/Y(\omega)}\, dx \\
& = Y(\omega)
\end{align*}

Does this seem correct?